# Dudas diagrama entidad/relación de SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, modelorelacional

Buenos días estoy empezando a trabajar con SQL Developer y cuando genero el diagrama entidad relación de unas tablas, no tengo muy claro el significado de las las letras azules de la izquierda, P, F, U.

Supongo que hacen referencia a la primary key, foreing key y not null, pero no entiendo bien si es eso o no gracias.

[image: Diagrama entidad/relacion SQL Developer]

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto y la U (Unique Key)